# I want to write a queue class for an Arduino project, but if I try to set everything to 0 it doesn't work and I can't iterate over all slots

Tags: c++, class, queue

```
#include <iostream>
class Queue
{
 public:
   int mLen;
   //int setupQueue(int);
   //void coutall();
   int TheQueue[];// I can't create the array in the setup funktion so it must be here
   void setupQueue(int Len)
   {
      mLen =Len;
      //TheQueue[100]= {10};//makes the queue 100 ints
      for(int e;e<199;e++)
       {
         TheQueue[e]= {200};
       }

   };
   void coutall()
     {
      std::cout<< mLen;
      for(int i;i<=mLen;i++)
       {
        int hV =TheQueue[i];
        std::cout<<hV<< std::endl;
       }
     };
```

Prints out all of the Elements
};

```
int main() {
Queue que;
que.setupQueue(200);
que.coutall();
return 0;
}
```

and generally some improvements are welcome.
in setup Should make all Elements to 0, but it doesn't work
and a lot of things also don't work

Comment: `TheQueue` is an empty array, you can't change its size later. `i` and `e` in your loops are uninitialised

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't understand at all what you are trying to do with setupQueue function, but try these things:
1- When you declare `int TheQueue[];`, you can't leave that `[]` empty, put the maximum size of your queue on it, if it's 500, then `int TheQueue[500];`. You should do this because this number indicates to the compiler how much space has to allocate.

1.5-Then mLen will have the real size of the queue, which obviously has to be smaller than the maximum.

2- This part: `for(int e;e<199;e++)` change 199 for a value within the range of allocated memory, which if we use the previous example, is from 0 to 500. For example you can use mLen(as I said at point 1.5).

3- If you want to set all the queue to 0, change this line:
`TheQueue[e]= {200};` //This creates an array with e elements, and each element is set to 200, so it's wrong, because you are creating an array 199 times setting all values to 200.

for this line:
`TheQueue[e]= 0;` //this assigns to the e position of the array a 0

4- There is a mistake in this function:

```
void coutall()
     {
      std::cout<< mLen;
      for(int i;i<=mLen;i++)
       {
        std::cout<< TheQueue[i] << std::endl;

       }
}
```

In this line: `for(int i=0;i<=mLen;i++)` change `<=` for `<`, becuase range is from 0 to mLen-1.

Recomendations:

1- It's not a good idea to implement the function inside the class.

2- You can simplify this:

```
int hV =TheQueue[i];
std::cout<<hV<< std::endl;
```

for this:

```
std::cout<<TheQueue[i]<< std::endl;
```

Your code will be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
class Queue
{
 public:
   int mLen;
   //int setupQueue(int);
   //void coutall();
   int TheQueue[500];// I can't create the array in the setup funktion so it must be here
   void setupQueue(int Len)
   {
      mLen =Len;
      for(int e;e<mLen;e++)
       {
         TheQueue[e]= 0;
       }

   };
   void coutall()
     {
      std::cout<< mLen;
      for(int i=0;i<mLen;i++)
       {
        std::cout<< TheQueue[i] << std::endl;

       }
     }
};
int main() {
Queue que;
que.setupQueue(200);
que.coutall();
return 0;
}
```